# Tkinter `after` strange behaviour

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a guitar tuning program on my PC. The main goal is to create an application that is able to capture audio using the microphone, do some analysis and outputting the results to the user, allowing them to tune up their instrument.

I came across a strange problem in one of my functions. I am trying to change a label two times - first, when the function starts and later when 3 seconds pass. However, the label updates only once (effectively showing only the `* recording...` text), at the end of the wait. What I also noticed, my whole GUI freezes once (I guess) it starts executing the `stateL` label `after`.

Code fragments (do not care about the pyAudio part, it's not changed yet):

```
    def gather_input(self):

        self.stateL.configure(text="Starting recording in 3 sec. Prepare!")
        self.stateL.after(3000, self.stateL.configure(text="* recording..."))


#        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
#
#        stream = p.open(format=self.FORMAT,
#                channels=self.CHANNELS,
#                rate=self.RATE,
#                input=True,
#                frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)
#        
#        frames = []
#
#        for i in range(0, int(self.RATE / self.CHUNK * self.RECORD_SECONDS)):
#            data = stream.read(self.CHUNK)
#            frames.append(data)
#
#        stream.stop_stream()
#        stream.close()
#        p.terminate()
#        
#        self.stateL.configure(text="Done recording!")
#        
#        return frames
```

Button line in my other function:

```
self.recButton = ttk.Button(self.mainLF, text="Start rec.", command=self.gather_input)
```

My goal after waiting 3 seconds is to go along with the function, save the sound sample and do some other things (for example, changing the label again when the recording ends, as it is `#` here). Also, I am not even sure if using `self.stateL.configure` in the `after` part is correct, or should I do this any other way.

Comment: No "strange" behavior. Just add a lambda expression. Change: `self.stateL.after(3000, self.stateL.configure(text="* recording..."))` to `self.stateL.after(3000, lambda: self.stateL.configure(text="* recording..."))`. With the after statement you need to save reference to a function call or use a lambda. What you have now will just execute instantly when that line is reached.

Comment: When I comment out the `self.stateL.configure(text="Done recording!")` now, it still stays at `* recording...` at the end. How to force the label to show `Done recording!` after the pyAudio thing finishes? Also, it doesn't show `Starting recording in 3 sec. Prepare!` in the label before it goes into `* recording...` text.

Comment: I think you are not understanding how `after()` works. It does not work like `sleep()` does. The rest of your code will execute right away and then 3 seconds later your after statement will execute. Where `sleep()` will make everything else wait for some time, the `after()` statement will execute some code after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the main issue in your question you need to use a lambda to fix that specific problem.

Change:

```
self.after(3000, self.stateL.configure(text="* recording..."))
```

To:

```
self.after(3000, lambda: self.stateL.configure(text="* recording..."))
```

To deal with your issues mentioned in the comments you may want to try the following.

You need to set up a few methods to make things work the way you want them too. You will also need to change a few variables to class attributes.

Try this and let me know if it helps.

```
def gather_input(self):
    self.stateL.configure(text="Starting recording in 3 sec. Prepare!")
    self.after(3000, self.start_recording)

def start_recording(self):
    self.stateL.configure(text="* recording...")
    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.FORMAT,
                              channels=self.CHANNELS,
                              rate=self.RATE,
                              input=True,
                              frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)

    self.after(3000, self.stop_recording)

def stop_recording(self):
    self.frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(self.RATE / self.CHUNK * self.RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = self.stream.read(self.CHUNK)
        self.frames.append(data)

    self.stream.stop_stream()
    self.stream.close()
    self.p.terminate()

    self.stateL.configure(text="Done recording!")
```